# Ns2 coding for resource allocation in CCRN

Tags: ns2

How to write the ns2 program for optimal resource allocation in ccrn cognitive radio network?
What is the coding for motion of nodes?

Comment: ? Do you mean CRCN ? ....  CRCN info : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/crcn/ , and https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ns-users/crcn|sort:date ....

Answer (score 0):

---

> What is the coding for motion of nodes ?

Motion : May be you mean "movement" ? http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/node172.html

CRCN : We have the "movement files" e.g. random.tcl, scenario2random.tcl, etc.

CRCN simulation examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNQ3BBR1hPc3V3aW8/view?usp=sharing

---

---